# geo-nodes control point distribution

Tags: geometry-nodes

i am trying to make a fishing rod in geo nodes. i am instancing the rings on the rod mesh, but there are way to many points. how do i decrease the count and control the distribution again? i remember how to do it with curves, but i need a mesh based distribution because i am animating the rod action with a simple deform modifier (which seems to affect the original mesh geometry only)

[image: fishing rod system]

Answer (score 4):

You can use **Mesh to curve** node and then resample it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *Mesh to Points* node literally converts every vertex on your mesh into a point, so you will need to somehow reduce the number of vertices along the length of the fishing pole to the exact number of rings you want.

[image]